# CDI Interceptors are not invoked in EJBs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, wildfly

I am trying to use CDI-like interceptors with EJB on Wildfly 8.2, but they are not invoked in any EJB. However, they are working just fine with CDI objects.

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DataTransferObject {

}
```

Interceptor to clone entity to DTO as return;

```
@Interceptor
@DataTransferObject
public class DataTransferObjectInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object clone(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception {
        Object actual = invocationContext.proceed();
        Object clone = actual.getClass().newInstance();
        BeanUtil.clone(actual, clone);
        return clone;
    }
}
```

The interceptor doesn't catch this;

```
@Stateless
@DataTransferObject
public class BaseCompanyService implements CompanyService {

    @EJB
    private CompanyDAO companyDAO;

    @Override
    public void create(Company entity) throws EntityException {
        companyDAO.create(entity);
    }

    .
    .
}
```

But it is working OK here;

```
@Path("/company")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@DataTransferObject
@Slf4j
public class CompanyResource implements Resource {

    @EJB
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @GET
    @Path("/check")
    @Override
    public Success check() {
        return new Success("The company service is running.");
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Success create(@Valid Company entity) throws EntityException {
        companyService.create(entity);
        log.info("The company with id \"{}\" is successfully created.", entity.getId());
        return new Success("The company is successfully created.");
    }

    .
    .
}
```

beans.xml

```
<interceptors>
    <class>io.rraa.interceptors.DataTransferObjectInterceptor</class>
</interceptors>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the interceptor to your business interface (i.e. CompanyService)?

Comment: @Franck I have added '@DataTransferObject' to interface classes, but still not being invoked.

Comment: Instead of **@EJB** to make the injection, you should try with **@Inject** to make sure CDI is invoked.

Comment: Can you try this annotation, maybe it helps: 
`@Interceptors({DataTransferObjectInterceptor.class})`